# Angular: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined Android Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular I am using this `$location.path('/login')` to move around the the app:

```
MainMenuCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$location'];
function MainMenuCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.doFileWeeklyClaim = function() {
        $location.path('/login');
    };
};
```

Only on Android::
When I redirect away from the app (say to google.com) and press `back` to come back to the app.  Upon clicking a link in the app the links no longer work. I get an error saying basically `location.href is undefined` (`Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`). The issue is in Angular v 1.0.8 and the error comes from `Angular.js` line `3268`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by following the approach suggested in the below link.

[Issue with Android native browser and angularjs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3814)

After following the above approach I could solve my issue, but the issue was also there in higher versions of android. For which I just changed the condition:

```
history: !!($window.history && $window.history.pushState && !(android < 5))
```